# PHP - filter_var REGEXP won't find Zero

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, zero, filter-var

I'm wondering why I can't match the number zero => 0 with PHPs filter_var function and with PHPs preg_match it can find the number zero.

Can anybody help me how I got this to work with *filter_var* or is this a bug ?

Code snippet:

```
if(!filter_var("0", FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options" => array("regexp" => '/^[0-9]+$/i')))) {
        print_r("NO MATCH!");
    } else {
        print_r("MATCH!");
    }
```

Result: **NO MATCH!**

Code snippet:

```
if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/i', "0") == 0) {
    print_r("NO MATCH!");
} else {
    print_r("MATCH!");
}
```

Result: **MATCH!**

Comment: `filter_var` and `preg_match` are two different functions and not interchangeable. And what you write in your title of the question is wrong. `filter_var` does find the zero with the code you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP function [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var) returns the filtered result. [From the PHP manual](http://php.net/filter_var#refsect1-function.filter-var-returnvalues):

> ### Return Values
>
> Returns the filtered data, or FALSE if the filter fails.

You practically did the same mistake as the user asking in [*filter_var using FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10993451/367456): The function does not validate input, it filters it. In case it does not match, it will return `FALSE` otherwise it will return the filtered data. And that is the string `"0"` which evaluates to `false` in PHP if you cast it to boolean which happens by using the negation operator (`!`).

Therefore you checked:

```
if (!"0") {
    print_r("NO MATCH!");
} else {
    print_r("MATCH!");
}
```

Which is what it is. So you output about "match" but you "if" about the value itself, not the match operation.

Write better code by just making use a simple variable assignment:

```
$var    = "0";
$result = filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options" => array("regexp" => '/^[0-9]+$/i')));

if (!$result) {
    print_r("NO MATCH!");
} else {
    print_r("MATCH!");
}
```

This will then allow you to trouble-shoot and change more easily:

```
var_dump($result); // string(1) "0"
```

And further:

```
$var    = "0";
$result = filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options" => array("regexp" => '/^[0-9]+$/i')));

if ($var !== $result) {
    print_r("NO MATCH!");
} else {
    print_r("MATCH!");
}
```

Is what you perhaps wanted to write earlier. Output:

```
MATCH!
```