# filter_var() ALPHA and Spaces only

Tags: php

How do we configure the `filter_var()` to validate a string which should only have ALPHA string and spaces?

I made the following however it returns `true` whenever either of the `$lastname` and `$firstname` has alphanumeric value.

```
    $namefields = '/[a-zA-Z\s]+/';
if (filter_var($firstname, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>$namefields))) == true &&
    filter_var($lastname, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>$namefields))) == true
        ) {
    echo("Success");
} else {
    echo("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some "anchors" to your regular expression; at the moment you're essentially asking it to match a string that **contains** a letter or white-space, rather than **only contains** letters or white-space.

Try

```
$namefields = '/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/';
```

The ^ matches the start of a string and the $ matches the end, meaning that the entire contents must match your character list.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter_var — Filters a variable with a specified filter
```

It can't validate whether the variable only includes ALPHA string and Spaces.

Use `preg_match` .