# How to protect DB::statement() from SQL injection in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, sql-injection, laravel-5.5

I want to let users create a database. The query looks like this:

```
DB::statement( 'CREATE DATABASE mydbname' )
```

I need to use `DB::statement` instead of `DB::select` / `DB::select` / `DB::update` as the latter commands do not support the `create` statement.

I want to protect myself from SQL injection and unfortunately, the following two methods do not work with `DB::statement`:

```
DB::statement( 'CREATE DATABASE :DBNAME', [ 'DBNAME', 'mydbname' ] );
DB::statement( 'CREATE DATABASE ?', [ 'mydbname' ] );
```

So how could I protect the `DB::statement` method from SQL injection? If that's not possible how could I trigger the `create` query in a protected laravel way without using raw PHP-PDO?

Comment: If you have to have a variable name for a table or column then your database is probably not set up very well.

Comment: What do you mean by that? How should a user else create a database? :)

Comment: My question is why you're letting users create a database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)

Comment: @castis: I'm writting a UI where they can manage their databases, what's so strange? :)

Comment: Didn't say it was strange, just wondering is all.

Comment: @chevallier Are the schemas for all databases equal, or can users create arbitrary tables? If they're all the same, simply add a `user_id` column to all tables and use a single database, giving access only to the values with that particular `user_id`. If not, the only thing I can think of is sanitizing all database and table names by limiting the characters in the variable to `[a-zA-z_]+` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993451/filter-var-using-filter-validate-regexp).

Comment: @Mike: Yes, that's the solution. Validate the request like this `'DatabaseName' => 'required|max:255|regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9]+$)/'` and that should be safe enough, because there could be no quotes at all. Thanks.